# Eleanor's Emoji Story

Tags: visual, rebus, emoji

A story told through emoji. Could be a book, show, movie, or some other kind of story. Can you figure out what story is depicted below?

[image: Android image version]

Text version:

> ❓❓⛪✒❓❓❓⛪❓❓

Comment: Your text version isn't working for me (the image is fine though)

Comment: @dcfyj The text version is highly dependent on a number of criteria, which is why the image is included.  Text version is mostly for the ability to copy/paste for those that want to.

Comment: Best I can tell, no one in chat can read the text version.

Comment: Didn't show up for me in Chrome, Firefox, Safari or the SE Android app

Comment: @Downvoter care to offer feedback?  I'd like to be able to improve on this style of puzzle.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but "Eleanor" in both the title and solution bugs me a little: maybe "Paul's Emoji Story" instead?  I did enjoy the puzzle though, and I'd like to see more in this vein.

Comment: The text version you pasted uses the Private Use Area. Actual emoji would use the emoji block in the Supplementary Multilingual Plane, which is 0x10000 code points higher. I'll edit in correct text.

Comment: I'm wondering if the OPs surname is a coincidence!?

Comment: @DamianYerrick Appreciate the edit.  I just made it in Google Hangouts and copy-pasted to the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks to me like

> Eleanor Rigby (the song by the Beatles)

Because

> It matches the lyrics uncannily. Here they are:
>
>  Ah look at all the lonely people
>  Ah look at all the lonely people
>  Eleanor Rigby, picks up the rice
>  In the church where a wedding has been
>  Lives in a dream
>  Waits at the window, wearing the face
>  That she keeps in a jar by the door
>  Who is it for
>  All the lonely people
>  Where do they all come from?
>  All the lonely people
>  Where do they all belong?
>  Father McKenzie, writing the words
>  Of a sermon that no one will hear
>  No one comes near
>  Look at him working, darning his socks
>  In the night when there's nobody there
>  What does he care
>  All the lonely people
>  Where do they all come from?
>  All the lonely people
>  Where do they all belong?
>  Ah look at all the lonely people
>  Ah look…

Comment: Well that was much quicker than expected...

Comment: Brilliant :) Both solver and asker !